# ProducesResponseType Type return for empty return

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is the typeof return to indicate there is empty body return. For example 401 unauthorized returns no body response except 401 status code.
`[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized))` is showing returning the following in swagger example

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "title": "string",
  "status": 0,
  "detail": "string",
  "instance": "string",
  "additionalProp1": {},
  "additionalProp2": {},
  "additionalProp3": {}
}
```

Comment: `"What is the typeof return to indicate there is empty body return"` usually `204` means successfully processed but return nothing. So you whould use `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]` [`You can get more details here in official docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-6.0#fields)

Comment: I need a 401 with no content. Is that achievable? @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Functional answer would be `No` directly you cannot achieve it. But there is workaround which you can achieve modifying your code which is not best practice. You can try like this: `var code = context.Response.StatusCode;`
                   `if (code == 401){await   context.Response.WriteAsync("No content for 401");}`

Comment: Could you share your controller details where you planned to return no content in response of 401?

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm late to the party on this one, but you can add `typeof(void)` to the `ProducesResponseType` like so:

```cs
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
```

This worked for me and is no longer showing a response body in Swagger.